# Как сказать правильно? Фобия к, или — перед?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Как сказать, что он страдал от жесточайшей ***фобии к*** или ***фобии перед*** (воздушными шарами)?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стал употреблять это слово ни в предложных, ни в безпредложных сочетаниях. По-моему, оно вообще плохо сочетается с другими словами. `Фобия пауков` звучит так, как будто это пауки страдают фобией. А в сочетаниях `фобия перед пауками` или `фобия к паукам` лучше заменить `фобию` на `страх` или `боязнь`.

Используйте или слово `фобия` само по себе, или конкретный термин: `арахнофобия`, `аэрофобия` и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "фобия" означает "боязнь", а значит использоваться должно так же, как и слово "боязнь".
Например: "фобия пауков", "фобия темноты".

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/29589)

Comment: @behemothus, я взял на себя смелость истолковать сказанное автором ответа в том виде, в котором его понял я. Сейчас жду одобрения предложенной мною правки.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky да видел я вашу правку... Пусть автор решает, я бы не рискнул за него такое решение принимать.

Answer (score 0):

***Аэростатофобия*** или ***баллонофобия***.

А в принципе - фобия, конечно, "к чему". Или чего. То есть "фобия к воздушным шарам", или "воздушных шаров". Первое более профессионально, второе - более распространено на бытовом уровне.

"Фобия перед" - сомнения вызывает некоторые, но если принять, что фобия = страх, то, видимо, и такое возможно. Не могу с ходу сказать, что встречал подобное.